# Operation not allowed on non-connected Sockets - C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, tcp, networkstream

It keeps having an error "Operation not allowed on non-connected sockets" on the line

```
var ServerStream = Connect2Server.GetStream();
```

And I'm not really sure why

Below is rest of the code for that function

```
var buffersize = 0;
var Convert2Tet = new ASCIIEncoding();
var Connect2Server = new TcpClient();
var ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8801);
var ServerStream = Connect2Server.GetStream();

Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Server");

Connect2Server.Connect(ServerEndPoint);
var WelcomeMessage = new byte[4096];
ServerStream.Read(WelcomeMessage, 0, 4096);

Console.Write(Convert2Tet.GetChars(WelcomeMessage));

var UserCredentials = Console.ReadLine();
buffersize = Convert2Tet.GetByteCount(UserCredentials);

var Credentials = new byte[buffersize];
Credentials = Convert2Tet.GetBytes(UserCredentials);

ServerStream.Write(Credentials, 0, buffersize);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You gotta Connect() before you can get the NetworkStream.

The documentation is usually pretty good for this kinda stuff. Under **Exceptions** in the help for [GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx), you'll see:

> InvalidOperationException: The
>   TcpClient is not connected to a remote
>   host.