# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.'

Tags: c#

This is my form

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7fuy.png

This is my code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace WindowsApplication1
    {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
          System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new 
                 System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    //NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
    //string readData = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msg("Client Started");
        clientSocket.Connect("192.168.0.167", 5000);
        label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        msg(returndata);
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox2.Focus();

    }


    public void msg(string mesg)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
    }


}
```

}

when I click the start button in the code i am getting this error to connect to the server. please guide me how to get rid of this error and connect to the server instead.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDSCI.png

Comment: Its normal that exceptions in form_load dont show - so clearly its not connecting.

Comment: what should i do to remove this error.

Comment: 1.l Not assume it made the connection. 2. move the connection to later, and check if it worked or not.

Comment: It didn't worked.

Comment: NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream(); //This is where I get this error.

Comment: I know.. because its not connected........ See earlier comment.. and how to fix,

Comment: I tried the earlier one but nothing happened.

Comment: what exactly did you do?

Comment: I want to connect to a ipaddress through socket connection. So first i created a server in console application and created a client in desktop application. So I gave ipaddress manually in client desktop application and and i want  to connect to the server by clicking start button but when I click start button it goes to this line. NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream(); and gives and error the operation is not allowed on connected socket.

Comment: So you didnt move the connect out of form_load.. You havent checked if the connection was made, your code has assumed it worked.. When you run this is the console app running? Is that your IP or a random one?

Comment: I did exactly that is available on this link. http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-server-socket.htm

Comment: I cant read that from work.. your question here needs to stand for itself, many people here have limitations on sites they can visit

Comment: My console app is running and in that command prompt server is running.

Comment: And i have also moved the connection from form load.

Comment: so, you should now get an error for the connect. now fix it :)

Comment: non socket connection basically the issue is connection.

Comment: so you need to fix that.. cant tell from here.

Comment: should i send you my file ?

Comment: no.. you have a choice of answering all my questions, or working it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170301/operation-not-allowed-on-non-connected-sockets-c-sharp-4-0) SO question.